# U-Boot debug diagnose why stuck after dtb device tree loaded and kernel not booting in Qemu kvm

Tags: embedded-linux, qemu, u-boot, device-tree, initrd

```
=> bootm 0x1000000 - 0x6000000

## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 01000000 ...
Image Name:   Linux-2.6.32.42
Image Type:   PowerPC Linux Kernel Image (gzip compressed)
Data Size:    3523176 Bytes = 3.4 MiB
Load Address: 00000000
Entry Point:  00000000
Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 06000000
Booting using the fdt blob at 0x6000000
Uncompressing Kernel Image ... OK
Loading Device Tree to 03ffc000, end 03fff5cf ... OK
WARNING: fdt_fixup_stdout: could not read serial0 alias: FDT_ERR_NOTFOUND
```

I don't think the `serial0` alias is the main problem, I'd expect more kernel messages showing that its actually trying to boot kernel. I am booting this in qemu emulator.

Appreciate tips on how to best diagnose debug this U-Boot issue.
Fyi that kernel uImage boots fine on real hardware board.

Comment: Side note: I suggest to stop doing necrofilia (2.6.32.y kernels) first. And if you are using serial connection the serial0 alias might be pretty much the ussue here.

Comment: thanks, I'd wish to upgrade to at least 3.18 or so but its not my call unfortunately. I think the problem was uImage kernel unpacking and/or mem address relocation ended up biting a chunk out of fdt memory address space.